Grouping postgres left join so it's just an array of the join data
I found this question
here
I'm having the same thing but needs a response a bit differently
const data = await db
  .select()
  .from(projects)
  .where(eq(projects.slug, slug))
  .leftJoin(projectPdfs, eq(projects.id, projectPdfs.projectId));

This gives me this data:
[
  {
    projects: { id: 1, name: 'redacted', slug: 'redacted' },
    pdfs: {
      id: 1,
      assetUrl: 'redacted',
      projectId: 1,
      requestTimeMs: '4859.872999999672'
    }
  },
  {
    projects: { id: 1, name: 'redacted', slug: 'redacted' },
    pdfs: {
      id: 2,
      assetUrl: ''redacted',
      projectId: 1,
      requestTimeMs: '4859.872999999672'
    }
  }
]

What I'm looking for is like this:
{
  project: { id: 1, name: 'redacted', slug: 'redacted' },
  pdfs: [
    {
      id: 1,
      assetUrl: 'redacted',
      projectId: 1,
      requestTimeMs: '4859.872999999672'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      assetUrl: ''redacted',
      projectId: 1,
      requestTimeMs: '4859.872999999672'
    }
  ]
}

I actually tried using groupBy but I didn't get the results I was after.

The tag [tag:sql] says "...and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used.".  It does not says that every possible DBMS, than can be used with [tag:drizzle] should be tagged.  Currently there is no SQL info in the question.

then you need to aggregate (json) projectPdfs before joining, ah i see your link already provided an answer

The link provided an answer but its' neglecting the data for the project @nbk

no, it only shows the subselect, the rest stays  the same as he has before, you need to read up how to do sibselects in drizzle

Can you ask your question using any one of the tables present in https://demo.drizzle.studio/ ?  (a.k.a.  [mre] )

You can achieve the desired result using the relations feature in Drizzle ORM, which automatically groups related data into arrays, avoiding the issue of repeated project data for each pdf.
Here’s how you can structure your projects and pdfs tables using Drizzle ORM:

Define your schemas with relations: Drizzle allows you to set up relations so that pdfs are grouped under their respective projects.


import { pgTable, integer, text } from "drizzle-orm/pg-core";
import { relations } from "drizzle-orm";

export const projects = pgTable("projects", {
  id: integer("id").primaryKey(),
  name: text("name"),
  slug: text("slug"),
});

export const pdfs = pgTable("pdfs", {
  id: integer("id").primaryKey(),
  assetUrl: text("assetUrl"),
  projectId: integer("project_id").references(() => projects.id),
  requestTimeMs: text("requestTimeMs"),
});

export const projectRelations = relations(projects, ({ many }) => ({
  pdfs: many(pdfs),
}));

export const pdfRelations = relations(pdfs, ({ one }) => ({
  project: one(projects),
}));



Query the projects with PDFs grouped as an array: With the relations set up, you can now query the projects table and get the associated PDFs grouped into an array under each project.


const result = await db.query.projects.findMany({
  with: {
    pdfs: true,  // PDFs will be grouped as an array under the project
  },
});


